# Is it possible to use WP7 AesManaged to reproduce NIST/FIPS197 results (AES128)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, encryption, aes

Howdy fellow programmers! I want to allow users of my software to securely transfer information from their Windows Phone devices to a couple of different services in the most convenient, common and platform independent way possible. Preferably with the tools already delivered by Microsoft. For this reason I looked into the AesManaged class that is available through the "System.Security.Cryptography" namespace in the Windows Phone SDK 7.1. However, so far I'm unable to even reproduce a single NIST example with this class. Amongst others I tried the following:

```
/* http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf page 35 and 36 */
var passwordBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
var unencryptedBytes = new byte[]{ 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff };        

using (var aes = new AesManaged())
{
    aes.BlockSize = 128; /* size in bits */
    aes.KeySize = 128; /* size in bits */
    aes.Key = passwordBytes; 

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(unencryptedBytes, 0, unencryptedBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

            var stream = memoryStream.ToArray();
            /* 
            should be 
            69-c4-e0-d8-6a-7b-04-30-d8-cd-b7-80-70-b4-c5-5a = 128 bit
            according to http://testprotect.com/appendix/AEScalc and fips-197.pdf
            */
            var output = BitConverter.ToString(stream); 
            /* 
            86-DB-4D-44-72-C0-16-E6-80-B9-D2-B2-3C-6D-00-40-98-4C-59-76-CF-41-DF-4E-A6-46-BB-DE-4C-13-E6-12 
            256 bit? 
            */
        }
    }  
}
```

I saw a couple of code examples (eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) that make use of IV and Rfc2898DeriveBytes (eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx), but what is the de-facto standard that is understood by every system by default? What is the default "Key Padding" algorithm and how to use it on a windows phone (maybe https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3394.txt or https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5649.txt ?). And lastely: Can I change the default (CBC according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.mode.aspx) to any other Mode on Windows Phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the document fails to point out is that they use all zeros for the Initialization Vector.  So set the IV to 16 bytes of all zero and it works:

```
/* http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf page 35 and 36 */
var passwordBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 
   0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f };
var unencryptedBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66,
   0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff };
var initvectorBytes = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

using (var aes = new AesManaged())
{
   aes.BlockSize = 128; /* size in bits */
   aes.KeySize = 128; /* size in bits */
   aes.Key = passwordBytes;
   aes.IV = initvectorBytes;

   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
         memoryStream, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
      {
         cryptoStream.Write(unencryptedBytes, 0, unencryptedBytes.Length);
         cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

         var stream = memoryStream.ToArray();
         /* now you get: 
            69-c4-e0-d8-6a-7b-04-30-d8-cd-b7-80-70-b4-c5-5a = 128 bit
            according to http://testprotect.com/appendix/AEScalc and fips-197.pdf
         */
         var output = BitConverter.ToString(stream);
      }
   }
}
```

For your application, you will want to make the IV something other than all zeros.  You wont be able to change the Mode using `AesManaged`, since AES is implemented using the CBC mode (or ECB).  You will get an exception if you try to set it to anything else.  You can change the Padding to whatever you like.  I would leave it as PKCS7 (the default).

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response. I did manage to almost get the desired result. However, for some reasion the output was 256 bit long: "69-C4-E0-D8-6A-7B-04-30-D8-CD-B7-80-70-B4-C5-5A-9E-97-8E-6D-16-B0-86-57-0E-F7-94-EF-97-98-42-32". This is caused by using "FlushFinalBlock" instead of just "Flush". I'm guessing that in contrast to Flush() the padding magic (PKCS7) is happening with the FlushFinalBlock() call and hence the difference?

Comment: What I find most interestingly is that AesManaged seems to set a random (?) IV in case one doesn't override the IV byte array manually. Very erratic behavior and unfortunately not even mentioned on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.iv(v=vs.95).aspx. I asked about Padding and Mode, because I couldn't find a way to set either of these properties with the WP7.1 SDK though apparently available on other platforms. Will get my code working and do some further testing and come back later.

Comment: I always use `FlushFinalBlock`.  If you dont want the extra block, just change the padding to `None`.  If the size of the data to encrypt equals the block size and padding is not `None`, you will get an extra block of data.

Comment: The extra data shouldnt be a concern, its just padding.  It will be removed when you decrypt it.  Their example just chose to use no padding.

Comment: Got it working in both directions (encryption/decryption). Thank you.